# Extraer número de un string a otro (php)

Tags: php

Hasta ahora he estado usando lo siguiente para extraer los números de un string:

`$numeros = filter_var($mistring, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);`

Pero me he fijado que en el caos de que no haya números en un string retorna `false` y yo necesito que me retorne o bien el valor numérico o bien un string vacío.

Bien es cierto que se puede hacer la función mencionada arriba y después hacer un `if` para ponerlo vacío si es false, pero preferiría que se haga directamente de algún modo.

Comment: Te recomiendo poner mas informacion en tu pregunta . para lograr entenderte mejor saludes

Comment: Lo que necesito es que un string por ejemplo `a1a2a3` se convierta en `123`

Comment: Si no quieres poner el if lo único que te queda por hacer es añadir un valor centinela al string. De esta forma te aseguras que siempre haya un numero, pero es una solución un poco chapuza.

Comment: Usando str_replace puedes eliminas  las partes del $mistring que no nesecitas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$numeros ='';    
$mistring = 'a1a2a3';

    $numeros = str_replace("a", "", $mistring);

    echo $numeros;
```

Espero sea lo que buscas saludes